# Secrets not being moved over when deploying Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

So I have this issue where in my `appname/current/config`, `appname/shared/config` and even `appname/currentRelease/config/` there is a `database.yml` but when I do the same steps to make secrets.yml appear in all three places, it refuses or isn't found. I have included `secrets.yml.sample` in my code repo to allow me to edit this on production, when I deploy but so far its failing.

What I have is:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "adambalan.com", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :rvm_install_type, :stable
before "deploy", "rvm:install_rvm"

set :rvm_ruby_string, "2.1.0"
before "deploy", "rvm:install_ruby"

require "rvm/capistrano"

set :application, "aisiswriter"
set :user, "railsapps"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:AdamKyle/Aisis-Writer.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"

namespace :rails do
  task :console, :roles => :app do
    hostname = find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
    exec "ssh -l #{user} #{hostname} -t 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rails console #{rails_env}'"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Start Application"
  task :start, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Stop Application (NOOP)"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  task :setup_secrets, roles: :app do
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config", "deploy:setup_secrets"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  task :symlink_secret, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config", "deploy:symlink_secret"

  # desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
   task :check_revision, roles: :web do
     unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
       puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
       puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
       exit
     end
   end
   before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

And the points to pay attention too are:

```
  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  task :setup_secrets, roles: :app do
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end

  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config", "deploy:setup_secrets"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  task :symlink_secret, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config", "deploy:symlink_secret"
```

The database.yml part of this conversation - as stated - works as I expect. its the secrets that does not. the file is there (100% is there) just not sure why its not copying over ...

When I look in the release directory I see:

```
AppName/
    releases/
        DateOfRelease/
            config/
                secrets.yml.sample # => Why you no copy over? You exist!!!!
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
task :setup_secrets, roles: :app do
    put File.read("config/database.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
end
```

that is obviously wrong.

You need

```
put File.read("config/secrets.yml.sample"), "#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"
```

so if your problem is that `secrets.yml` is not created, that is the problem (and the solution), you create the `database.yml`file twice instead of the `secrets.yml`.